signInWithRedirect Returns null response
I'm new for firebase, and tried a simple sign-in button, running on a local React.js app (with node.js).
firebase credentials are loaded in 'firebase.js'. This code is of a component with login button, and a listener for redirection
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from './firebase'; // Ensure this file exports your initialized Firebase auth
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithRedirect, getRedirectResult, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // Handle sign-in
  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing in: ", error);
    }
  };


  // Check redirect result
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRedirectResult = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
        console.log("fetch redirected, result:", result);

        if (result) {
          setUser(result.user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting redirect result:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchRedirectResult();
  }, []);

  // Monitor auth state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("auth changed, user:", user);
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {user ? (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome, {user.displayName}!</p>
          <button onClick={handleSignOut} style={buttonStyle}>Sign Out</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleSignIn} style={buttonStyle}>Sign In with Google</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const buttonStyle = {display: 'flex',alignItems: 'center',backgroundColor: '#4285F4',color: '#fff',padding: '10px 20px',border: 'none',borderRadius: '4px',cursor: 'pointer',fontSize: '16px',};

export default App;

Running the exact same code with signInWithPopup  works OK. I saw that authorized domains may be an issue, but i'm running on localhost which is  already in there.
I checked the console logs, and no errror found, only null users showed:
fetch redirected, result: null

auth changed, user: null

Is it anything bad in the code?
